# 5 V, 3 A to 5 V 3 A current limiter for DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, current-limiting

[image]

I've found a 5 V 3 A motor and I tested it using a lab power supply that limits the current draw to 3 A.

I've bought a 5 V, 3 A power supply without thinking that the motor would draw too much current if possible. In fact, it does draw too much current and the power supply goes into security mode about every 0.5 seconds.

How can I limit the current to 3A with a small circuit?

Here is the power supply I bought: https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=433054

Here are 2 photos of the motor, I can't find the datasheet.

Btw, I assumed it's a 5V 3A motor: the lab power supply can only deliver currents up to 3A and I adjusted to voltage to 5V.

Comment: The job of the power supply is to provide the motor with as much current as it wants, not how much the supply wants it to have.

Comment: Load the motor less. If it won't even start you probably need a more suitable power supply.

Comment: what's the difference between the two pictures?  What is each telling us the other can't?

Comment: I've removed one of them, I'm new here and I appreciate your comment, I'll try to improve for my next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bought the wrong power supply.  No only does it have too low current output, but its over-current behavior is not what you want.

The supply should be able to handle the startup current, not the nominal running current.  The startup current is probably considerably more than 3 A.

The supply should go into *current limiting* when the load tries to draw too much current.  Yours shuts off for a second or two.  That's not what you want.

The reason this works with your 3 A lab supply is because it is a current limiting type.  At startup when the motor tries to draw more than 3 A, the supply's output voltage drops to where the motor only wants to draw 3 A.  As the motor spins up, the 3 A point goes higher and higher in voltage.  When it gets to 5 V (if it ever does), the supply then regulates the voltage to 5 V, and the current goes down as the motor speed increases further.

Comment: I'll do measurements and research before buying anything else, thanks a lot for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

The 3 A rating is probably the maximum running load. Starting the motor will require a much higher current.

If you still have the lab power supply you can run another test and this time record the voltage output of the supply while the motor is drawing 3 A.

I think you will find that the PSU is causing the motor to start in current limited mode which will cause the motor to run at constant torque. If the motor can accelerate to running speed then the PSU will limit the voltage at 5 V and the motor will run in "constant speed" mode.

With the motor disconnected you should also measure the motor resistance. From this you can calculate the starting current.

Update your question with the results and further answers will follow.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that when I connect the motor to the 5v 3a DC power supply I bought, it starts spinning for 0.5 seconds then it stops for 0.5s and it does that repeatedly. It must mean that 3a is enough for the motor to start spinning...

Comment: You've already proven that 3 A is enough to spin the motor. The problem is that your new supply has a different over-current protection scheme. You haven't linked to a datasheet for that or the motor so nobody can help you further. Note that it's capital 'A' for ampere and 'V' for volt. (I fixed your title and most of your post.) Capitals matter.

Comment: Sorry for the gigantic photos, I've no clue how to make them appear smaller without changing their resolution

Comment: Imgur uses 's', 'm', 'l' (small, medium, large) before the '.png' or '.jpg' to resize. Done.